# Excel VBA Userform keeps resizing

Tags: excel, vba, resize, userform, autoresize

When I'm using my external monitor and close an executing userform, it returns to the Visual Basic Windows smaller than designed, as shown below.

[image: Userform with a reduced size after execution]

What happens is, if I execute it again without reajusting, it goes to the user with this reduced proportion.

It behaves like this only with an external monitor (I've tried different ones, same result).

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the monitors using a different zoom setting?

Comment: @braX Yes, both at 100%, although different resolutions.

Comment: I don't have a good answer, but I am pretty sure it's related to DPI Scaling. Maybe someone else will know the details about how to control it.

Comment: This is a bug I noticed too, I think it has its root that they never really looked into multi displays and no one bothered to look at it in detail, however, if you really need, maybe you could find [this link](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/userforms/positioning.htm) useful to your needs, perhaphs setting in the first place in the second monitor could avoid this

Comment: This is a bug that needs to be reported to Microsoft. They don't update the VBE or VBA very often so it's unlikely to be fixed. WinForms don't handle scaling well. It's one of the things fixed in WPF. Microsoft would need to rewrite the VBE in WPF.

Comment: This is not a programming question and there is no programming solution outside of writing all of the form properties in code to be set at initialization.

Comment: just a side note: If you want to change your resolutions and zoom to try different things, make sure to restart excel each time you change them too if you want to see the effect of the change

Comment: I think it's somehow related to hardware, because this bug didn't exist in my previous thinkpad. Now I'm using a Dell with a geforce mx330, and sometimes even the W11 windows shows up with scale diferences